# Solving SDE:$\frac{dy(t)}{dt}=(c+\sigma_wW(t))y(t)+\epsilon(t) $

Tags: stochastic-differential-equations

I want so solve the following SDE. Specifically, I want to know if $y(t)$ is a Gaussian Process and if so the corresponding mean and covariance function.

$$\frac{dy(t)}{dt}=(c+\sigma_wW(t))y(t)+\epsilon(t) $$ 11

where $W(t)$ is the [Wiener process](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wiener_process), $\epsilon(t) \sim \mathcal{N}(0,\sigma^2_e)$ for all $t$ and all the $e(t)$ random variables are mutually indepedent, $\sigma_w$ is a non-negative scalar and $c \in \mathbb{R}$.

I don't have any background in solving stochastic differential equations. Thus, my approach so far has been trying mathematica, which was not too successful yet.

Comment: Is any information about $\epsilon (t)$ ?

Comment: Can you write it as :$dy(t)=c dt +\epsilon (t) dt +\sigma_w y(t)dw(t)$ ?

Comment: @Khosrotash I added more information about $\epsilon(t)$. If one wants to write it in your form I think it should be $$dy(t) = cdt + e(t)dt + \sigma_w y(t)W(t)dt$$ The wiener process is used a bit differently as it is used usually.

Comment: Is $\epsilon(t)$ a continuous process?

Comment: yes, $\epsilon(t)$ is actually a gaussian process with mean function $m(t)=0$ and kernel function $m(t,t')=\delta_{tt'}\sigma_\epsilon^2$

Comment: Well such a process cannot exist. See this question: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1207453/impossible-stochastic-process

Comment: Can you elaborate on this a bit? In my understanding $y(t)$ does not fullfill the first two assumptions in your question. I do not understand the third assumption.

Comment: I am talking about $\epsilon(t)$ itself. You cannot force it to be continuous.

Comment: Hey, i guess my comment about $\epsilon(t)$ being continuous was wrong. $\epsilon(t)$ is a stochastic process. More specifically it is a Gaussian white noise process, i.e., it is a Gaussian process with mean function $m(t,t')=0$ and covariance function $k(t,t')=\sigma_\epsilon^2$ if $t=t'$ and $0 $ otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

By conditioning on $W(t)$, this is a regular ODE

$$y'=a(t)y(t)+b(t)$$

and it has the solution [First-order equation with variable coefficients](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_differential_equation#First-order_equation_with_variable_coefficients)

$$y(t)=ce^{\int^{t} a(s)ds}+e^{\int^{t} a(s)ds}\int b(s)e^{-\int^{t} a(s)ds}.$$